# How can you display values from a table in Code.org App Lab?

Tags: javascript, database, calculator, code.org, app-lab

I have made a calculator in the Code.org App Lab using JS - [Caclulator v1.0](https://studio.code.org/projects/applab/Yfb7qbw1YmqaL-dwm2Eq_gISOiWE0hxHxIKTtbWRnKo)

In this calculator, every time the equal button is pressed, `problemText`, `problemText_2`, `operator`, and `answerText` are placed in a record in the table,  `arithCalc`. There is a screen in the calculator,  which is meant to display the previous calculations. in a `textArea` or table. Is there any way to use `readRecords()` to obtain the values from the table, and display them in the `textArea` in `arithDisplay` or in a table in `arithDisplay`?

Here is the code:

```js
//ARITHMETIC CALCULATOR

var problemText;
var operator;
var problemText_2 = "";
var answerText;

onEvent("arithButton","click", function() {
  setScreen("arithmeticScreen");
  });

//button1
onEvent("b1","click",function() {
  problemText = getText("problemBox");
  setProperty("problemBox", "text", problemText + "1");
  problemText =(getText("problemBox"));
  console.log(problemText);
  
  if (problemText != null) {
    setProperty("plusButton","hidden",false);
    setProperty("minusButton","hidden",false);
    setProperty("multiplyButton","hidden",false);
    setProperty("divisionButton","hidden",false);
  } else {
    setProperty("plusButton","hidden",true);
    setProperty("minusButton","hidden",true);
    setProperty("multiplyButton","hidden",true);
    setProperty("divisionButton","hidden",true);
  }
  
  if (problemText.length  > 4) {
    setProperty("b0","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b1","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b2","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b3","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b4","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b5","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b6","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b7","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b8","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b9","hidden",true);
  }
});

//button2
onEvent("b2","click",function() {
  problemText = getText("problemBox");
  setProperty("problemBox", "text", problemText + "2");
  problemText =(getText("problemBox"));
  console.log(problemText);
  
  if (problemText != null) {
    setProperty("plusButton","hidden",false);
    setProperty("minusButton","hidden",false);
    setProperty("multiplyButton","hidden",false);
    setProperty("divisionButton","hidden",false);
  } else {
    setProperty("plusButton","hidden",true);
    setProperty("minusButton","hidden",true);
    setProperty("multiplyButton","hidden",true);
    setProperty("divisionButton","hidden",true);
  }
  
  if (problemText.length  > 4) {
    setProperty("b0","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b1","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b2","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b3","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b4","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b5","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b6","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b7","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b8","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b9","hidden",true);
  }
});

//button3
onEvent("b3","click",function() {
  problemText = getText("problemBox");
  setProperty("problemBox", "text", problemText + "3");
  problemText =(getText("problemBox"));
  console.log(problemText);
  
  if (problemText != null) {
    setProperty("plusButton","hidden",false);
    setProperty("minusButton","hidden",false);
    setProperty("multiplyButton","hidden",false);
    setProperty("divisionButton","hidden",false);
  } else {
    setProperty("plusButton","hidden",true);
    setProperty("minusButton","hidden",true);
    setProperty("multiplyButton","hidden",true);
    setProperty("divisionButton","hidden",true);
  }
  
  if (problemText.length  > 4) {
    setProperty("b0","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b1","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b2","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b3","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b4","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b5","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b6","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b7","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b8","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b9","hidden",true);
  }
});

//button4
onEvent("b4","click",function() {
  problemText = getText("problemBox");
  setProperty("problemBox", "text", problemText + "4");
  problemText =(getText("problemBox"));
  console.log(problemText);
  
  if (problemText != null) {
    setProperty("plusButton","hidden",false);
    setProperty("minusButton","hidden",false);
    setProperty("multiplyButton","hidden",false);
    setProperty("divisionButton","hidden",false);
  } else {
    setProperty("plusButton","hidden",true);
    setProperty("minusButton","hidden",true);
    setProperty("multiplyButton","hidden",true);
    setProperty("divisionButton","hidden",true);
  }
  
  if (problemText.length  > 4) {
    setProperty("b0","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b1","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b2","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b3","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b4","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b5","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b6","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b7","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b8","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b9","hidden",true);
  }
});

//button5
onEvent("b5","click",function() {
  problemText = getText("problemBox");
  setProperty("problemBox", "text", problemText + "5");
  problemText =(getText("problemBox"));
  console.log(problemText);
  
  if (problemText != null) {
    setProperty("plusButton","hidden",false);
    setProperty("minusButton","hidden",false);
    setProperty("multiplyButton","hidden",false);
    setProperty("divisionButton","hidden",false);
  } else {
    setProperty("plusButton","hidden",true);
    setProperty("minusButton","hidden",true);
    setProperty("multiplyButton","hidden",true);
    setProperty("divisionButton","hidden",true);
  }
  
  if (problemText.length  > 4) {
    setProperty("b0","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b1","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b2","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b3","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b4","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b5","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b6","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b7","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b8","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b9","hidden",true);
  }
});

//button6
onEvent("b6","click",function() {
  problemText = getText("problemBox");
  setProperty("problemBox", "text", problemText + "6");
  problemText =(getText("problemBox"));
  console.log(problemText);
  
  if (problemText != null) {
    setProperty("plusButton","hidden",false);
    setProperty("minusButton","hidden",false);
    setProperty("multiplyButton","hidden",false);
    setProperty("divisionButton","hidden",false);
  } else {
    setProperty("plusButton","hidden",true);
    setProperty("minusButton","hidden",true);
    setProperty("multiplyButton","hidden",true);
    setProperty("divisionButton","hidden",true);
  }
  
  if (problemText.length  > 4) {
    setProperty("b0","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b1","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b2","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b3","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b4","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b5","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b6","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b7","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b8","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b9","hidden",true);
  }
});

//button7
onEvent("b7","click",function() {
  problemText = getText("problemBox");
  setProperty("problemBox", "text", problemText + "7");
  problemText =(getText("problemBox"));
  console.log(problemText);
  
  if (problemText != null) {
    setProperty("plusButton","hidden",false);
    setProperty("minusButton","hidden",false);
    setProperty("multiplyButton","hidden",false);
    setProperty("divisionButton","hidden",false);
  } else {
    setProperty("plusButton","hidden",true);
    setProperty("minusButton","hidden",true);
    setProperty("multiplyButton","hidden",true);
    setProperty("divisionButton","hidden",true);
  }
  
  if (problemText.length  > 4) {
    setProperty("b0","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b1","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b2","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b3","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b4","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b5","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b6","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b7","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b8","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b9","hidden",true);
  }
});

//button8
onEvent("b8","click",function() {
  problemText = getText("problemBox");
  setProperty("problemBox", "text", problemText + "8");
  problemText =(getText("problemBox"));
  console.log(problemText);
  
  if (problemText != null) {
    setProperty("plusButton","hidden",false);
    setProperty("minusButton","hidden",false);
    setProperty("multiplyButton","hidden",false);
    setProperty("divisionButton","hidden",false);
  } else {
    setProperty("plusButton","hidden",true);
    setProperty("minusButton","hidden",true);
    setProperty("multiplyButton","hidden",true);
    setProperty("divisionButton","hidden",true);
  }
  
  if (problemText.length  > 4) {
    setProperty("b0","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b1","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b2","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b3","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b4","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b5","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b6","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b7","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b8","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b9","hidden",true);
  }
});
  
//button9
onEvent("b9","click",function() {
  problemText = getText("problemBox");
  setProperty("problemBox", "text", problemText + "9");
  problemText =(getText("problemBox"));
  console.log(problemText);
  
  if (problemText != null) {
    setProperty("plusButton","hidden",false);
    setProperty("minusButton","hidden",false);
    setProperty("multiplyButton","hidden",false);
    setProperty("divisionButton","hidden",false);
  } else {
    setProperty("plusButton","hidden",true);
    setProperty("minusButton","hidden",true);
    setProperty("multiplyButton","hidden",true);
    setProperty("divisionButton","hidden",true);
  }
  
  if (problemText.length  > 4) {
    setProperty("b0","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b1","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b2","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b3","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b4","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b5","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b6","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b7","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b8","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b9","hidden",true);
  }
});

//button0
onEvent("b0","click",function() {
  problemText = getText("problemBox");
  setProperty("problemBox", "text", problemText + "0");
  problemText =(getText("problemBox"));
  console.log(problemText);
  
  if (problemText != null) {
    setProperty("plusButton","hidden",false);
    setProperty("minusButton","hidden",false);
    setProperty("multiplyButton","hidden",false);
    setProperty("divisionButton","hidden",false);
  } else {
    setProperty("plusButton","hidden",true);
    setProperty("minusButton","hidden",true);
    setProperty("multiplyButton","hidden",true);
    setProperty("divisionButton","hidden",true);
  }
  
  if (problemText.length  > 4) {
    setProperty("b0","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b1","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b2","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b3","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b4","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b5","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b6","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b7","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b8","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b9","hidden",true);
  }
});

onEvent("divisionButton","click", function() {
  operator = "÷";
  
  setProperty("plusButton","hidden",true);
  setProperty("minusButton","hidden",true);
  setProperty("multiplyButton","hidden",true);
  setProperty("divisionButton","hidden",true);
  
  setProperty("b0b","hidden",false);
  setProperty("b1b","hidden",false);
  setProperty("b2b","hidden",false);
  setProperty("b3b","hidden",false);
  setProperty("b4b","hidden",false);
  setProperty("b5b","hidden",false);
  setProperty("b6b","hidden",false);
  setProperty("b7b","hidden",false);
  setProperty("b8b","hidden",false);
  setProperty("b9b","hidden",false);
  
  setProperty("problemBox","text",problemText + " " + operator);
  
  problemText = Number(problemText);
  
  problemText_2 =  "";
  
  /*createRecord("arithCalc",{num1:problemText, operator:"÷"});*/
});

onEvent("plusButton","click", function() {
  operator = "+";
  
  setProperty("plusButton","hidden",true);
  setProperty("minusButton","hidden",true);
  setProperty("multiplyButton","hidden",true);
  setProperty("divisionButton","hidden",true);
  
  setProperty("b0b","hidden",false);
  setProperty("b1b","hidden",false);
  setProperty("b2b","hidden",false);
  setProperty("b3b","hidden",false);
  setProperty("b4b","hidden",false);
  setProperty("b5b","hidden",false);
  setProperty("b6b","hidden",false);
  setProperty("b7b","hidden",false);
  setProperty("b8b","hidden",false);
  setProperty("b9b","hidden",false);
  
  setProperty("problemBox","text",problemText + " " + operator);
  
  problemText = Number(problemText);
  
  problemText_2 =  "";
  
  /*createRecord("arithCalc",{num1:problemText, operator:"÷"});*/
});

onEvent("multiplyButton","click", function() {
  operator = "×";
  
  setProperty("plusButton","hidden",true);
  setProperty("minusButton","hidden",true);
  setProperty("multiplyButton","hidden",true);
  setProperty("divisionButton","hidden",true);
  
  setProperty("b0b","hidden",false);
  setProperty("b1b","hidden",false);
  setProperty("b2b","hidden",false);
  setProperty("b3b","hidden",false);
  setProperty("b4b","hidden",false);
  setProperty("b5b","hidden",false);
  setProperty("b6b","hidden",false);
  setProperty("b7b","hidden",false);
  setProperty("b8b","hidden",false);
  setProperty("b9b","hidden",false);
  
  setProperty("problemBox","text",problemText + " " + operator);
  
  problemText = Number(problemText);
  
  problemText_2 =  "";
  
  /*createRecord("arithCalc",{num1:problemText, operator:"÷"});*/
});

onEvent("minusButton","click", function() {
  operator = "-";
  
  setProperty("plusButton","hidden",true);
  setProperty("minusButton","hidden",true);
  setProperty("multiplyButton","hidden",true);
  setProperty("divisionButton","hidden",true);
  
  setProperty("b0b","hidden",false);
  setProperty("b1b","hidden",false);
  setProperty("b2b","hidden",false);
  setProperty("b3b","hidden",false);
  setProperty("b4b","hidden",false);
  setProperty("b5b","hidden",false);
  setProperty("b6b","hidden",false);
  setProperty("b7b","hidden",false);
  setProperty("b8b","hidden",false);
  setProperty("b9b","hidden",false);           
  
  setProperty("problemBox","text",problemText + " " + operator);
  
  problemText = Number(problemText);
  
  problemText_2 =  String("");
  
  /*createRecord("arithCalc",{num1:problemText, operator:"÷"});*/
});

onEvent("b0b","click",function() {
  problemText_2 = problemText_2 + String(0);
  setProperty("problemBox", "text", problemText + " " + operator + " " + problemText_2);
  console.log(problemText_2.length);
  problemText_2 =  problemText_2;
});

onEvent("b1b","click",function() {
  problemText_2 = problemText_2 + String(1);
  setProperty("problemBox", "text", problemText + " " + operator + " " + problemText_2);
  console.log(problemText_2.length);
  problemText_2 =  problemText_2;
});

onEvent("b2b","click",function() {
  problemText_2 = problemText_2 + String(2);
  setProperty("problemBox", "text", problemText + " " + operator + " " + problemText_2);
  console.log(problemText_2.length);
  problemText_2 =  problemText_2;
});

onEvent("b3b","click",function() {
  problemText_2 = problemText_2 + String(3);
  setProperty("problemBox", "text", problemText + " " + operator + " " + problemText_2);
  console.log(problemText_2.length);
  problemText_2 =  problemText_2;
});

onEvent("b4b","click",function() {
  problemText_2 = problemText_2 + String(4);
  setProperty("problemBox", "text", problemText + " " + operator + " " + problemText_2);
  console.log(problemText_2.length);
  problemText_2 =  problemText_2;
});

onEvent("b5b","click",function() {
  problemText_2 = problemText_2 + String(5);
  setProperty("problemBox", "text", problemText + " " + operator + " " + problemText_2);
  console.log(problemText_2.length);
  problemText_2 =  problemText_2;
});

onEvent("b6b","click",function() {
  problemText_2 = problemText_2 + String(6);
  setProperty("problemBox", "text", problemText + " " + operator + " " + problemText_2);
  console.log(problemText_2.length);
  problemText_2 =  problemText_2;
});

onEvent("b7b","click",function() {
  problemText_2 = problemText_2 + String(7);
  setProperty("problemBox", "text", problemText + " " + operator + " " + problemText_2);
  console.log(problemText_2.length);
  problemText_2 =  problemText_2;
});

onEvent("b8b","click",function() {
  problemText_2 = problemText_2 + String(8);
  setProperty("problemBox", "text", problemText + " " + operator + " " + problemText_2);
  console.log(problemText_2.length);
  problemText_2 =  problemText_2;
});

onEvent("b9b","click",function() {
  problemText_2 = problemText_2 + String(9);
  setProperty("problemBox", "text", problemText + " " + operator + " " + problemText_2);
  console.log(problemText_2.length);
  problemText_2 =  problemText_2;
});

setInterval(function() {
  if (problemText_2.length > 4) {
    setProperty("b0b","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b1b","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b2b","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b3b","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b4b","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b5b","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b6b","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b7b","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b8b","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b9b","hidden",true);
    
    setProperty("b0","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b1","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b2","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b3","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b4","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b5","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b6","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b7","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b8","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b9","hidden",true);
  }
},1);

onEvent("homeButton","click", function() {
  setScreen("startScreen");
});

onEvent("equalButton","click", function() {
  if (operator === "÷") {
    problemText = Number(problemText);
    problemText_2 =  Number(problemText_2);
    answerText = (problemText/problemText_2).toFixed(5);
  } else if (operator === "×") {
    problemText = Number(problemText);
    problemText_2 =  Number(problemText_2);
    answerText = problemText*problemText_2;
  } else if (operator === "+") {
    problemText = Number(problemText);
    problemText_2 =  Number(problemText_2);
    answerText = problemText + problemText_2;
  } else if (operator === "-") {
    problemText = Number(problemText);
    problemText_2 =  Number(problemText_2);
    answerText = problemText - problemText_2;
  }
  
  setText("answerBox",String(answerText));
  
  createRecord("arithCalc",{num1:problemText, operator:operator, num2:problemText_2, result:answerText},  function() {
    setProperty("b0b","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b1b","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b2b","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b3b","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b4b","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b5b","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b6b","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b7b","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b8b","hidden",true);
    setProperty("b9b","hidden",true);
    
    setProperty("b0","hidden",false);
    setProperty("b1","hidden",false);
    setProperty("b2","hidden",false);
    setProperty("b3","hidden",false);
    setProperty("b4","hidden",false);
    setProperty("b5","hidden",false);
    setProperty("b6","hidden",false);
    setProperty("b7","hidden",false);
    setProperty("b8","hidden",false);
    setProperty("b9","hidden",false);
    
    problemText = undefined;
    setProperty("problemBox","text","");
    operator = undefined;
    problemText_2 = "";
    answerText = undefined;
    setText("answerBox","");
  });
});

onEvent("clearButton","click",function() {
  setProperty("b0b","hidden",true);
  setProperty("b1b","hidden",true);
  setProperty("b2b","hidden",true);
  setProperty("b3b","hidden",true);
  setProperty("b4b","hidden",true);
  setProperty("b5b","hidden",true);
  setProperty("b6b","hidden",true);
  setProperty("b7b","hidden",true);
  setProperty("b8b","hidden",true);
  setProperty("b9b","hidden",true);
    
  setProperty("b0","hidden",false);
  setProperty("b1","hidden",false);
  setProperty("b2","hidden",false);
  setProperty("b3","hidden",false);
  setProperty("b4","hidden",false);
  setProperty("b5","hidden",false);
  setProperty("b6","hidden",false);
  setProperty("b7","hidden",false);
  setProperty("b8","hidden",false);
  setProperty("b9","hidden",false);
  
  problemText = undefined;
  setProperty("problemBox","text","");
  operator = undefined;
  problemText_2 = "";
  answerText = undefined;
  setText("answerBox","");
});

onEvent("previousResults","click",function() {
  setScreen("displayArithmetic");
});
//ARITHMETIC CALCULATOR



//DISPLAY ARITHMETIC RESULTS

onEvent("homeButton_pc","click",function()  {
  setScreen("startScreen");
});

//DISPLAY ARITHMETIC RESULTS
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `arithDisplay` a variable? It is not displayed anywhere, or I could not find it. Please reduce your code size down to what is important.

```js
readRecords("table",{},function(records) {
 for(var i = 0 ; i < records.length ; i++) {
  setText("id",record[i].text);
 }
});
```

that should accomplish what I think you want. Also, instead of writing `setProperty()` you could just use `setText()` which is shorter.